# iPhone: Setting section titles from an Array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have an XML file, two nodes, text and title.

I'm trying to `progrmatically` set the section title from an `array` I've built up.

Is there a way I can do similar to the following (but I'm not sure how to bring in the item row?)

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrySummaryTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
}
```

How else do you set the section title from an `Array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be misunderstanding something... What you'd want to make your example work is replace your line with  `return [arrySummaryTitle objectAtIndex:section];`, right?
`