# Loading Section Title From an Array

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am a newbie here. I have a UITableView in which I load data dynamically. I know how to pass values from an array to a cell. But, I would like to have multiple sections in my table and want to pass different section titles for the sections I have. Is there anyway I can pass String values from an array to the "titleForHeaderInSection" method?? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prior SO question/answer should give you what you want?

[iPhone: Setting section titles from an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270500/iphone-setting-section-titles-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

In your TableViewDelegateProtocol handler implement

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Create a UIView with a UILabel subView holding the text you want to display and return it.  The easiest way to create the HeaderView would be via an xib file.

Comment: Thanks John.. The above answer worked for me. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I actually showed you the had way - should have used - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section.